# Binding Picture box

Tags: c#, winforms, ado.net

I want to know if we can bind a picturebox as this example :

```
Binding b = new Binding("Image", dataset, "Timage.imagee");
pictureBox1.DataBindings.Add(b);
```

Comment: You already knew this in your previous question: [Can not add images to a database using disconnect mode](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22863642/719186)

Comment: but i want to know why i can't do that with disconnect mode ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Format event of the Binding object:

```
Binding b = new Binding("Image", dataset, "Timage.imagee", true);
b.Format += picFormat;
pictureBox1.DataBindings.Add(b);

private void pic_Format(object sender, ConvertEventArgs e)
{
  Bitmap bmp = null;
  byte[] img = (byte[])e.Value;
  using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) {
    ms.Write(img, 0, img.Length);
    bmp = new Bitmap(ms);
  }
  if (bmp != null) {
    e.Value = bmp;
  }
}
```

Comment: I have an error when i click to add button private void buttonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.BindingContext[dataset, "Timage"].AddNew();

            SqlCommandBuilder sql = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataadapter);
            dataadapter.Update(dataset, "Timage");}  in this line  byte[] img = (byte[])(e.Value);  e.value don't receive anything i have this error : Unable to cast an object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.Byte []'.       dbNULL VALUE HELP

Comment: @JohnLow I posted an answer to your question, but I don't know what else you are doing since now you are adding SqlCommandBuilders to the equation.

Comment: Yes for adding a row to my database and update and delete by bindingcontext and sqlcommandBuilder this is my objectif we can do that  ? if you want i send you all my project by email if you want if you are free now ?

Comment: @JohnLow You just need to document your question with enough information where we can see or duplicate the problem.  Your question only asked if DataBinding works with a PictureBox, and I tried to show a way that it does.  You probably have to also add the Parse event, which performs the opposite of the Format event: it takes an image and you convert it into bytes[].  If this is a new question, then open a new question and document it thoroughly.

Comment: I have tried  to add a true parameter but the same probleme e.value is null